# Why i getting this error Bad Request HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed

Tags: php, curl

I want to upload a document in one drive in folder and Send curl request for uploading and getting bad request error.

```
$uri = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.6971fd0b7e644a5a.6971FD0B7E644A5A!329/files/phocapdf-demo.pdf?access_token=EwAQA61DBAAUGCC....';    

protected function curl_put($uri, $fp) {
    $output = "";
    $pointer = fopen($fp, 'r+');
    $stat = fstat($pointer);
    $pointersize = $stat['size'];

    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $pointer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, (int)$pointersize);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));         

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->dd($output); //get error
}
```

This fucntion is use for debuging

```
function dd($value)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($value);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: What is the $uri please ?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra i update my code noe check.